# Onclick button targeting a single form in an array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, forms, onclick

I am trying to have a button display a hidden form within an array of php data. It is working except I can't get it to only open one form at a time. When you click any of the buttons all of the forms are displayed. I have tried using a variable as the class that but then the function stops working all together.

```
function deptStaffOptions ($deptId, $company){
    $retVal = "";

    // Connect to the database by creating a new mysqli object
    include "DBconnect.php";
    $query = "
    SELECT
        s.staffId,
        s.fName,
        s.lName
    FROM staff AS s
    INNER JOIN agencies AS a ON a.company = s.company
    WHERE s.company = '$company' AND s.archive = 0 AND s.staffId NOT IN (
      SELECT staffId FROM deptAgts WHERE deptID = $deptId)
      ORDER BY s.fName";


    $retVal = $retVal . "<button class='work' id='dept". $deptId ."'>Please Work</button><form class='work' class='dept". $deptId ."' style='display: none;'><select>";


    if ($resultCD = $mysql->query($query)) {
        while ($aRow = $resultCD->fetch_assoc()) {

            $retVal = $retVal . "<option value='".$aRow['staffId']."'>". $aRow['fName'] . " " . $aRow['lName'] . "</option>";
        }
    }

    $retVal = $retVal . "</select></form>";
    return $retVal;

    $mysqli->close();

}

print deptStaffOptions($deptId, $company);
```

This is the initial javascript I was working with:

```
<script>
    $( "button.work" ).click(function() {
        $( "form.work" ).show( "fold", 1000 );
    });
</script>
```

This works but all of the forms open when any button is clicked.

In the one below the `id` is being found in the alert, but then I tried testing the class with actual data (not automatically generated) and it stopped working.

```
<script>
    $( "button" ).click(function() {
        var department = (this.id);
        alert(department);
        $( "form.dept23" ).show( "fold", 1000 );
    });
</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two class attributes in one tag. Just split classes with a space.

```
$retVal = $retVal . "<button class='work' id='dept". $deptId ."'>Please Work</button><form class='work dept". $deptId ."' style='display: none;'><select>";
```

You can dynamically select using:

```
<script>
    $( "button" ).click(function() {
        var department_id = (this.id);
        $( "form.dept" + department_id).show( "fold", 1000 );
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I made the changes and it still isn't worked.  Thanks for catching the class issue.

Comment: Can you make an example using the outputted HTML on https://jsbin.com/. I think this is definitely a JS issue.

Comment: The whole page is based on a lot of SQL data. Would it help if I place a larger chunk of the code here? Could it also be happening because the html is being created by a PHP function?

Comment: It'd help to have an example of the HTML that PHP is generating.